# Client Server Chat Application in Java without broadcasting

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am working on a school project where I have to design a client server chat application in Java using Socket programming and HTTP protocol. I should ensure that the message does not get broadcasted to every client; instead the message should only reach the client it is destined for. Since I am new to Socket Programming, I have been looking for some tutorials all over the internet, but all I could find was where the message gets broadcasted. Any help or any links to tutorials would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the ability to create public/private chatrooms.  So many others have gone into specifics. This should be a good starting point:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524120/A-Java-Chat-Application